# Massage Preview on with table data instead demo value Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image: I want like this]  Here is my code You can also test it in jsfiddle, I want to preview massage in preview_show div but when user click on button then instead of that sample text in textarea(like:#&#0) I want to show the coulmn value in each massage , I am able to get table column array But dont know now what to do Please suggest me logic .In simple words on click preview table column values in each massage
Please help me with this. Thank you

```
     <table border="1" id='csvtb'>
<thead>
<tr>
<td>
    <p>name</p>
    <input type="button" class="sal" value="0">
    </td>
    <td>
        <p>contect</p>
        <input type="button" class="sal" value="1">
        </td>
        <td>
            <p>email</p>
            <input type="button" class="sal" value="2">
            </td>
            <td>
                <p>address</p>
                <input type="button" class="sal" value="3">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>arpit</td>
                <td>56546546</td>
                <td>a@a.com</td>
                <td>211,ed,45,dff</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>arpit1</td>
                <td>56546546</td>
                <td>a@a.com1</td>
                <td>211,ed,45,dff</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>arpit2</td>
                <td>56546546</td>
                <td>a@a.com</td>
                <td>211,ed,45,dff</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
<br>
<input id="showtext" type="hidden" >
<br>
<textarea id="massage"></textarea>
<br>
    <button id="preview">Preview</button>
    <div id="show_preview" style="border:solid 1px gray;"> lkjlkj</div>

    <script>     
    var mtxt=document.getElementById('massage').value;
    $( document ).ready(function() {   
    $('.sal').click(function() {
    var oldm=$('#massage').val();
    values =$(this).val(); // add value to array
    values='#&#'.concat(values+' ');
    console.log(values+oldm);
    $('#massage').val(oldm+values);
    //$('#showtext').val(values);
    $('#massage').focus();
    });
    $('#massage').on('input', function() {
    var org=$('#massage').val();    
    $("#showtext").val(org);
    });  
    var trCount=    $( "#csvtb thead tr:nth-child(1) td" ).length;
    //console.log(trCount);
    for(i=1;i<=trCount;i++){
    //console.log(trCount);
    var tdata=($('#csvtb tbody td:nth-child('+i+')').map(function(){
    return $(this).text();
    }).get());
    //var tg.push(tdata);
    }   console.log(tdata);
    }); 
    </scirpt>
```

Comment: Where to massage??

Comment: Preview massage in div with id (show_preview)

Comment: Clicking on, suppose `email` button, What to show in `textarea`??

Comment: if you edit it in jsfiddle then you able to know what I am trying to do. please help

Comment: Where is jsFiddle link ?

Comment: @ArpitPathak If you want all respective column values in the textarea, I've added an answer.

Comment: I edited the question added an image please have a look

Answer (score 0):

Have a Try.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src = "jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<table border="1" id='csvtb'>
    <thead>
    <tr>
    <td>
        <p>name</p>
        <input type="button" class="sal" value="0">
        </td>
        <td>
            <p>contect</p>
            <input type="button" class="sal" value="1">
            </td>
            <td>
                <p>email</p>
                <input type="button" class="sal" value="2">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <p>address</p>
                    <input type="button" class="sal" value="3">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>arpit</td>
                    <td>56546546</td>
                    <td>a@a.com</td>
                    <td>211,ed,45,dff</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>arpit1</td>
                    <td>56546546</td>
                    <td>a@a.com1</td>
                    <td>211,ed,45,dff</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>arpit2</td>
                    <td>56546546</td>
                    <td>a@a.com</td>
                    <td>211,ed,45,dff</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    <br>
    <input id="showtext" type="hidden" >
    <br>
    <textarea id="massage"></textarea>
    <br>
        <button id="preview">Preview</button>
        <div id="show_preview" style="border:solid 1px gray;"> lkjlkj</div>

        <script>     
            var mtxt=document.getElementById('massage').value;

            $( document ).ready(function() {

                $('.sal').click(function() {
                    var oldm=$('#massage').val();
                    values =$(this).val(); // add value to array

                    var colVal = [];
                    $('tr:gt(0)').each(function () {
                      colVal.push($(this).find('td:eq('+values+')').text());
                    });

                    values='#&#'.concat(values+' ');
                    console.log(values+oldm);
                    //$('#massage').val(oldm+values);
                    $('#massage').val(colVal.join(" "));
                    //$('#showtext').val(values);
                    $('#massage').focus();
                });

                $('#massage').on('input', function() {
                    var org=$('#massage').val();    
                    $("#showtext").val(org);
                });  

                var trCount=    $( "#csvtb thead tr:nth-child(1) td" ).length;
                //console.log(trCount);
                for(i=1;i<=trCount;i++){
                //console.log(trCount);
                    var tdata=($('#csvtb tbody td:nth-child('+i+')').map(function(){
                       return $(this).text();
                    }).get());
                //var tg.push(tdata);
                }   console.log(tdata);
            }); 

        </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No brother You change the code. think about only to append text into show_preview div but we only have to change the text which we are getting in textarea by clicking buttons change that text in div with each coloumn and leave the rest

Comment: @ArpitPathak Can you show me with an example?? suppose I Click on address, email button, What to show in `show_preview` div??

Comment: You only have to replace the text which is getting in text area from the original text of table coulmn

Comment: @ArpitPathak `show the tr value on particular email ` What does it mean?? What values to show?? Explain with an example. You need to explain clearly if you need a solution else Ignore it!